# I cannot remove the errors from the jUnit test?

Tags: java

```
package lib;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;

public class ModuleTest {

    /* Both the default and 2 argument custom constructor should initialise the coursework
     * and exam weighting to 50.
     */
    @Test
    public void testDefaultConstructor() {
        Module m = new Module();

        //default modules should get a code of CTEC0000
        assertEquals("Code field should be initialised with CTEC0000", "CTEC0000", m.getCode());
        assertEquals("Name field should be initialised with an empty string", "", m.getName());
        assertEquals("Exam weight field should be initialised to 50", 50, m.getExamWeight());
        assertEquals("Cwk weight field should be initialised to 50", 50, m.getCwkWeight());
    }

    @Test
    public void testCustomConstructor2arg() {
        Module m = new Module("CTEC2602", "OO Development");

        assertEquals("Code field should be initialised with CTEC2602", "CTEC2602", m.getCode());
        assertEquals("Name field should be initialised with OO Development", "OO Development", m.getName());
        assertEquals("Exam weight field should be initialised to 50", 50, m.getExamWeight());
        assertEquals("Cwk weight field should be initialised to 50", 50, m.getCwkWeight());
    }

    /* The 3 argument custom constructor should accept a value for the exam weighting and then ensure
     * the coursework weighting is set so their combined total add up to 100. The following two tests check
     * this works correctly. One test is not sufficient as the value could have been hardcoded.
     */
    @Test
    public void testCustomConstructor3args_1() {
        Module m = new Module("CTEC2602", "OO Development", 60);

        assertEquals("Code field should be initialised with CTEC2602", "CTEC2602", m.getCode());
        assertEquals("Name field should be initialised with OO Development", "OO Development", m.getName());
        assertEquals("Exam weight field should be initialised to 60", 60, m.getExamWeight());
        assertEquals("Cwk weight field should be initialised to 40", 40, m.getCwkWeight());
    }

    @Test
    public void testCustomConstructor3args_2() {
        Module m = new Module("CTEC2901", "Data Structures", 70);

        assertEquals("Code field should be initialised with CTEC2901", "CTEC2901", m.getCode());
        assertEquals("Name field should be initialised with Data Structures", "Data Structures", m.getName());
        assertEquals("Exam weight field should be initialised to 70", 70, m.getExamWeight());
        assertEquals("Cwk weight field should be initialised to 30", 30, m.getCwkWeight());
    }

    @Test
    public void testSetAndGetCode() {
        Module m = new Module();
        m.setCode("CTEC2602");

        assertEquals("Code field should be set to and return CTEC2602", "CTEC2602", m.getCode());
    }

    @Test
    public void testSetAndGetName() {
        Module m = new Module();
        m.setName("OO Development");

        assertEquals("Name field should be set to and return OO Development", "OO Development", m.getName());
    }

    /* As well as testing the set/get methods for exam and cwk weight behave in a normal way, we also
     * need to ensure they check that the combined exam and cwk weighting adds up to 100.
     */
    @Test
    public void testSetAndGetExamWeight() {
        Module m = new Module();
        m.setExamWeight(60);

        assertEquals("Exam weight field should be set to and return 60", 60, m.getExamWeight());
    }

    @Test
    public void testSetExamWeightUpdatingCwkWeight() {
        Module m = new Module();
        m.setExamWeight(60);

        assertEquals("Cwk weight field should be set to 40", 40, m.getCwkWeight());
    }

    @Test
    public void testSetAndGetCwkWeight() {
        Module m = new Module();
        m.setCwkWeight(70);

        assertEquals("Cwk weight field should be set to and return 70", 70, m.getCwkWeight());
    }

    @Test
    public void testSetCwkWeightUpdatingExamWeight() {
        Module m = new Module();
        m.setCwkWeight(70);

        assertEquals("Exam weight field should be set to 30", 30, m.getExamWeight());
    }

    @Test
    public void testToString() {
        Module m = new Module("CTEC2602", "OO Development");
        String toStr = m.toString();

        assertTrue("The toString method should be in the standard convention format",
                toStr.startsWith("Module:[") &&
                toStr.contains("=" + m.getCode() + ", ") &&
                toStr.contains("=" + m.getName() + ", ") &&
                toStr.contains("=" + m.getExamWeight() + ", ") &&
                toStr.endsWith("=" + m.getCwkWeight() + "]"));
    }

}
```

This top is the object and the class is not working with it this is what I have so far.

```
package main;

public class Module {

    //Fields
    private String code;
    private String name;
    private int examWeight;
    private int cwkWeight;


    //Constructors
    public Module() {
        this("CTEC0000", "", 50);
    }

    public Module(String code, String name) {
        this(code, name, 50);
    }

    public Module(String code, String name, int examWeight) {
        this.code = code;
        this.name = name;
        this.examWeight = examWeight;
        this.cwkWeight = 100 - examWeight;
    }


    //Methods
    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getExamWeight() {
        return examWeight;
    }

    public void setExamWeight(int examWeight) {
        this.examWeight = examWeight;
        this.cwkWeight = 100 - examWeight;
    }

    public int getCwkWeight() {
        return cwkWeight;
    }

    public void setCwkWeight(int cwkWeight) {
        this.cwkWeight = cwkWeight;
        this.examWeight = 100 - cwkWeight;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Module:[code=" + code + ", name=" + name +
                ", examWeight=" + examWeight + ", cwkWeight=" + cwkWeight + "]";
    }

}
```

I keep getting errors in the top code saying module cannot be resolved to a type help please.

Comment: Did you import `Module`?

Comment: @resueman this can be rewritten as answer... and maybe a short example (and adding that usually a test class resides in the same package as the class being tested)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here :

```
package lib;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;

public class ModuleTest {
```

`main.Module` class is not imported.
So typing `Module m = new Module();`
without the full qualified name is not recognized by the compiler.

`main.Module m = new main.Module();` is correct for the compilation but it reduces the readability in this case.
 So importing `Module` class in `ModuleTest` seems more suitable :

```
package lib;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;
import main.Module;

public class ModuleTest {
```

Anyway, if you use an IDE, you should have a option to resolve automatically the missing imports. So, use it.
 
Besides, a good practice is to use the same package for the test class than for the tested class.
 As a side-effect, you would not need to import `Module` class in `ModuleTest` class.
Ideally `Module` and `ModuleTest` should be in the same package but not in the same folder : one for testing and the other one for the application.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
import main.Module;
```

to the ModuleTest.java file.